# Synology disk group

Tags: software-raid, synology

For the moment i've 1 4TB HDD on my synology DS1513+. I'm transfering all my data on it but when this HDD will be full, i'll add a second 4TB HDD.

How to have 1x8TB and not 2x4TB on my synology without losing data just by "resizing" volume1 ?

And same for 1x(sum of all HDD capacity) instead of 5x(HDD capacity) ?

Comment: Anyway, a possible solution would be a RAID in striping mode (thus this requires to have the disks when you set up the RAID array) or a LVM (that allows you to add more disks later on, but then you either need a filesystem that supports resizing or you need to distribute your data over multiple partitions).

Source :  Abrixas2 from stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your volume is using Synology Hybrid Raid (SHR) adding a drive is very easy.  See this [tutorial](http://www.synology.com/en-us/support/tutorials/559).  That is what I did when I went from 3 to 4 HDD's in my DS411+ii.  You can set up a SHR array with just one disk if that is not what you are currently using.  Keep in mind with just one disk you will not have redundancy.  With 2 4TB HDD's only 4TB will be available on the SHR array, but you will have redundancy.  The volume will expand once you have 3 or more 4TB HDD's, but since you have a 5 bay device I imagine you planned on expanding anyway.

In response to your comment: If you do not want redundancy but do want the ability to expand the disks later, set up your volume as JBOD.  According to the first tutorial in section 2: "DiskStation supports expanding capacity of volumes and Disk Groups with the following RAID types: Synology Hybrid RAID (SHR), JBOD, RAID 5, RAID 5+ Spare, and RAID 6."  Thus, the only option which allows expandability without redundancy is JBOD.  This [tutorial](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/tutorials/558) will show you how to create a JBOD volume if yours is not currently one.

Comment: Why "with 2 4TB HDD's only 4TB will be available on the SHR array" ? It's true even if i don't want any data redundancy ?

Comment: Thx for the tutorial !!!

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: I'll work to follow your edited answer, then vote up if success your answer :)